# Way to associate a keyboard shortcut to mouse event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wiriting an Ajax web application with jQuery.

I need to link almost every click event to a keyboard shortcut.

My idea is to use a function like this to bind the events:

```
$.fn.myclick = function(element, key, customFunction) {
  $("body").on("click keypress", element, function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === key || event.keyCode === undefined) {
      customFunction();
    }
  });
};
```

I'm quite sure this is not a good way and you do know a best way to perform this task.
I think the problem with my method would be that the event could be fired even when I change page and I press the key. I should add some kind of unbind or a way to fire the event only when the user is on the correct page.
The pages are just a list of `<section>` hidden with `display: none;` except for the one active.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at js libs for handling  keyboard events. Choose any you (or the community) like: http://microjs.com/#keyboard

Comment: Thanks but looks like no one of them has something for what I need (click besides keyboard)